# Cin is being ignored in while and for loops

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

Alright well I'm a newbie with C++ so I'm doing some exercises in Lippman's *C++ Primer 5th Edition* and the function never even prompts the user for an input. I'm very frustrated as none of my produced code worked and neither does this from an answer key. This only produces "0" when compiled and ran. Any help is appreciated. Compiled on a x64 Mac.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int val; std::cin >> val; sum += val);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want it to prompt for output you have to code it.  Otherwise it just expects you to start entering in data.

Comment: What did you type for input?

Comment: works for me on [ideone](http://ideone.com/LG9a9S)

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I didn't type in an input as the program never gave me an opportunity to enter any. @PeteBecker.                                I'm compiling via the Terminal. GabrielF

Comment: @StanDarsh check the compiler version with `g++ --version`. Also, please add commandline you are using to compile and any messages being given in either compiling or running.

Comment: Maybe adding some debugging too. If you add a `std::cout << "teste" << std::endl` as the very first line of your main, will it print it?

Answer (score 1):

The program works, it just works differently than what you expect!

It expects you to keep entering numbers separted by whitespace, then giving end-of-file (ctrl-Z on Windows, ctrl-d on Unix on empty line) or other invalid input, so that `cin` goes to fail state.

And when `cin` goes to fail state, then it gives false to `for` loop (due to implicit cast to bool using an overloaded bool cast operator), which ends. Then your program prints them sum. If you didn't manage to enter any numbers, then it prints 0, as that is what `sum` was initialized to.

Comment: I'm sure I'm making an error but I don't understand what it is. I'm not getting the opportunity to enter numbers at all. I'm compiling via g++ in macs terminal and then running it using ./

Comment: @StanDarsh Add example terminal session (copy-paste preferred over screen shot, unless you think the screen shot shows something copypasted text would not). You could also add debug prints to the code (use cerr, not cout), and check the various status methods offered by cin to see just why it fails.